Left border of funnel chart not drawing after setting borderSkipped: false in ChartJS 3.8.x
I have this funnel chart:
this.chartLeads2 = new FunnelChart(document.getElementById("graphLead2").getContext('2d'), 
        {
          data: {
            labels: ["TOTAL Q LEADS", "WAITING", "ACHIEVED"],
            datasets: [
              {
                borderSkipped: false // this doesn't work
                data: [this.leads.won + this.leads.waiting, this.leads.waiting, this.leads.won],
                borderColor: [this.borderColors[0],this.borderColors[1],this.borderColors[2]],
                backgroundColor: [this.bgColors[0],this.bgColors[1],this.bgColors[2]],
                datalabels: {
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: (context) => {
                    return this.borderColors[context.dataIndex];
                  },
                  font: {
                    size: 12,
                  },
                  formatter: (value, context) => {
                    const label = context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
                    return `${label}\n${(value).toLocaleString()}`;
                  }
                },
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            elements:{
              trapezoid:{
                borderSkipped: false // this doesn't work
              },
              bar:{
                borderSkipped: false // this doesn't work
              }
            }
          },
          plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        }
      )

Everything works fine except borderSkipped: false, which didn't make the left border appear. I tried setting borderSkipped: 'top' but it too didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?


That's a bit of a strange one and might need to be raised as an issue with the plugin. The borderSkipped property comes from Chart.js and only applies to the 'Bar' type, so is not having any effect on the trapezoid. The first place you have placed it (in datasets) is correct for bars, and this is demo'd here: https://codepen.io/skandog/pen/gOyZmWx

Alternatively you might want to have a look at extending the plugin code directly, or creating your own plugin to bridge the border gap

or skip having a border

@Skandog I thought the left border was hidden only in horizontal bar charts. Is trapezoid some sort of modified bar or something like that?

Yeah I noticed the difference when the indexAxis is switched, in which case it's the other edge which disappears. This package is using an extension of the BarChart, which the developer has titled TrapezoidElement (export class TrapezoidElement extends BarElement: https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-funnel/blob/main/src/elements/TrapezoidElement.ts). However it is overriding the draw method, and I don't see anything in there that corrects for the borderSkipped functionality with that.

As discussed by @Skandog, this is a bug; we can see it in the source code
at TrapezoidElement#draw;
there are the four points returned by the call to this.computeWayPoints();, but there are only three lines connecting the points,
in the subsequent for; it could be solved by adding a ctx.closePath() at line 265.
Until the bug is solved by the developers, you may as well patch it, by repeating the start point at the end of the polygon
returned by TrapezoidElement#computeWayPoints:


const TrapezoidClass = Chart.registry.elements.get('trapezoid');
if(TrapezoidClass){
    const original_computeWayPoints = TrapezoidClass.prototype.computeWayPoints;
    if(original_computeWayPoints){
        TrapezoidClass.prototype.computeWayPoints = function(useFinalPosition){
            const wp = original_computeWayPoints.call(this, useFinalPosition);
            if(useFinalPosition === undefined && wp.length === 4){
                // this is the call from draw, the others have a default useFinalPosition=false
                wp.push(wp[0]); // close the polygon
            }
            return wp;
        }
    }
}
const data = {
    labels: ["TOTAL Q LEADS", "WAITING", "ACHIEVED"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [1, 0.75, 0.5],
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "black"
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: "funnel",
    data,
    options: {
        indexAxis: "y"
    }
};


new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chartjs-chart-funnel"></script>



Sidenote: You haven't mentioned the plugin you were using, and I was a little bit confused by the use of the borderSkipped property - it
is not used at all by chartjs-chart-funnel,  but it is used extensively in
the Chart.Funnel.js plugin, which seems unrelated.

Really strong answer.
